# Centralised node_modules

Tags: node.js, debian, npm, node-modules

I would like to have my Node modules stored in a centralised place, in say, `/var/http/common/` and have my app live/run in a different location, say `/var/http/www/apps/APP#1_NAME/`.

I was able to set up the requires in `server.js` to use relative paths like `require('../../../common/express')`, but from reading [posts](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/775#issuecomment-1389398) by NPM's author, it sounds like I'm hacking it, and I should use `npm link` to create a "local" reference for Node (which symlinks to the real installation).

I first installed my node modules in `/var/http/common/`, but then when I tried to create the symlink (`npm link ../../../common/node_modules/express`), npm seems to have treated it like a "global" install, and re-installed express in `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/express` (and created a "local" symlink to it `./node_modules/express ->`) which is not what I expected to happen. Is this what I actually want? Should I have used `npm config set prefix` first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out: I should have set `npm config set prefix` before doing anything else.

It might appear that `npm link` and `npm install -g` do the same thing; however whilst, `npm link` will install the module globally, it *also* creates a local symbolic link in `node_modules` pointing to `$prefix/lib/node_modules/$module`. [MaxGfeller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867998/758177) is incorrect: Without that local symlink, Node will complain that it cannot find the (globally installed) modules. This is determined thru my own attempts as well as is inferred from `npm help folders`:

> • Install it **locally** if you're going to **require()** it.
>
> • Install it **globally** if you're going to run it on the **command line**.
>
> • If you need **both**, then install it in both places, or use **npm link**.

This doesn't specifically address what I asked: I want to have the modules stored in a central location (to be accessed by multiple Node Applications) but I don't care about using them from the command like—I only want to use them in `require('')`.

As for my question about using relative paths in `require('')`, I still have not got/found an authoritative answer for that, but it would seem from the existance of `npm link` that using rel paths is not the author's intent. To me it seems like a case of [six-of-one](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_of_one,_half_a_dozen_of_the_other), but I would like to remain consistent with Node's standard.

Comment: think you need $NODE_PATH set to avoid the local sym link

Answer (score 2):

You can install your node modules globally using by adding '-g' to the command. For example:

```
npm install express -g
```

In your code you can use it normally:

```
require('express');
```

The modules are then stored in /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks, but I don't want them installed in that location (Should I have used npm config set prefix first?). Also I was asking because I didn't run npm install, I ran npm link; so I want to know why it also ran an install—is it maybe because it detected that the modules were not installed in the default global location?